# Trying to subplot to put 8 figures into 2 windows

Tags: matlab, plot, subplot, figure

```
  x = [1 3 4 6 9];
    y = x + 3;

 stem(x); xlabel('My x axis'); ylabel('My y axis'); title('No title --:)'); 
 grid on;
 hold on;
stem(y);
```

i have 8 graphs that are made using this format, i am trying to have them appear into 2 windows with 4 graphs on each, when i try to make a new file using subplot the graphs look completely different. what am i doing wrong?

image 1 is the correct graph
image 2 is me trying to put it into subplot

```
x = [1 3 4 6 9];
y = x + 3;
subplot(2,2,1), plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need 2 loops. One loop for figures, another loop for subplots within each figure:

```
for i = 1:2
    figure; % this creates a separate figure
    
    for j=1:4
        subplot(2,2,j);
        x = randi(10, 1, 4);
        y = x + 3;
        stem(x); xlabel('My x axis'); ylabel('My y axis'); title('No title'); 
        grid on;
        hold on;
        stem(y);
    end
end
```